How to check if pair of column values appear in another dataframe?
To simplify the situation, let's say I have a 2 dataframes with 2 columns (User_id, User_name) each.
I want to remove the entries that appear in both tables, specifically, I would like to adjust the following to handle multiple columns:
df1=df1[~df1.user_id.isin(df2.user_id)]

Is this doable?

for multiple columns, look into merge, probably doing a left merge, and using the parameter indicator=True, you'll be able to select only the rows that are in left_only.

Yes, this is doable. You need to modify your code as below.
df1 = df1[~(df1.user_id.isin(df2.user_id) & df1.user_name.isin(df2.user_name))]

For multiple columns, a better approach would be to do a pd.merge() with indicater = True and then select only the rows where right table columns are null.

The multiple isin approach is incorrect if the targets should be in the same row.

Correct, this will not work if the matching should happen in pairs.
